# How to add JomSocial top menus in custom components

Tags: php, menu, joomla2.5

I am developing a website with JomSocial component. There are few more component that I have developed.

I want to add top menus e.g. Profile, photos, fiends, groups etc... menus in my developed comopments.

Please help me how to add these menus in my developed components.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may help you http://www.jomsocial.com/support/docs/item/779-Welcome-to-MyBlog!.html

Comment: 404 Article not found ... :(